# IntelliJ: Break point set in another module of maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a question regarding how to debug a maven project with multiple modules in IntelliJ.

I have a project which contains two modules: client and shared.

The "shared" is just a jar and the "client" depends on "shared". The client has a unit test which internally will call a class defined in the "shared" module.

However, if I setup a break point in the "shared" module, IntelliJ won't stop on that break point and simply ignore that.

My question is that how I can debug in this scenario?

Many thanks.

Comment: This should *just work*. Are you sure you have the correct version of the JAR and sources of `shared` module attached?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run the Unit test in Debug mode? Or did you perform a Maven build which executes the unit tests? If yes, you should try to configure the surefire plugin to wait until you attached a debugger to debug your tests.

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html for more details.